# Metadata Deployment Stuck in the Pending Status

Tags: deployment, metadata

I am attempting to deploy some metadata configurations from a production instance to a dev instance.

I am using SublimeText/MavensMate to handle the deployment.

I can see the deployment arrive in the target instance but it simply sits in a pending state (10hrs so far)

[image: Pending Status]

I'm also seeing a "Polling Time Out" error within MavensMate:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! The solution would be is, cancel and deploy again. There is no troubleshoot step for these issues.

Comment: Thanks @Ashwani - I ended up reducing the metadata components for this deployment until a meaningful error message was presented.  I then corrected the errors until a deployment was successful and then I deployed the remaining components in layers.

Comment: It happens because Snailsfarce is truly terrible.